# Any way to reference Lambda function from AWS Serverless Application Repository in CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk

My plan is using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/using-access-points.html to protect PII info leakage in some S3 buckets

I found guide for doing S3 Access Point with CDK here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3objectlambda-readme.html

However, I don't have prior experience with CDK. The example seems to be for Lambda functions that are zipped and hosted on our S3. Is there any way to use the ComprehendPiiAccessControlS3ObjectLambda function in the AWS Serverless Application Repository?